# ESLint rule to prevent string from appearing in string or template literal

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I'd like an ESLint rule to prevent the string "foo" from appearing anywhere in strings or template literals, so both statements would be in violation:

```
const str1 = 'foo bar';
const str2 = `foo ${bar}`;
```

I configured [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) to handle strings, handling `str1` from the example above,

```
'no-restricted-syntax': [
    'error',
    'Literal[value=/foo/]',
],
```

, but what's the equivalent syntax to handle template literals?

Comment: https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/d982acf8d9245f27ef6a3c953a18dc33/bcb3404a56c53a286b9d40a1b410114c68f528b1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector syntax would be `TemplateElement[value.cooked=/foo/]` ([**demo**](https://eslint.org/play/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiLyogZXNsaW50IFwibm8tcmVzdHJpY3RlZC1zeW50YXhcIjogW1xuICAgIFwiZXJyb3JcIixcbiAgICBcIkxpdGVyYWxbdmFsdWU9L2Zvby9dXCIsXG4gICAgXCJUZW1wbGF0ZUVsZW1lbnRbdmFsdWUuY29va2VkPS9mb28vXVwiXG5dICovXG5cbmNvbnN0IHN0cjEgPSAnZm9vIGJhcic7XG5jb25zdCBzdHIyID0gYGZvbyAke2Jhcn1gO1xuIiwib3B0aW9ucyI6eyJwYXJzZXJPcHRpb25zIjp7ImVjbWFWZXJzaW9uIjoibGF0ZXN0Iiwic291cmNlVHlwZSI6InNjcmlwdCIsImVjbWFGZWF0dXJlcyI6e319LCJydWxlcyI6e30sImVudiI6e319fQ==)), e.g.

```
'no-restricted-syntax': [
    'error',
    'Literal[value=/foo/]',
    'TemplateElement[value.cooked=/foo/]',
],
```

Contrasted with a [`Literal`](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/34c5f6c52819a9ed16d8f0cff31e8f61c8a6593b/es5.md#literal) node, a [`TemplateElement`](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/34c5f6c52819a9ed16d8f0cff31e8f61c8a6593b/es2015.md#templateelement)'s `value` is an object with two properties: `cooked` (similar to `Literal[value]`) and `raw` (analogue of `Literal[raw]`).